# Intel Alder Lake support in Linux 5.15.0-46-generic x86_64 kernel, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: kernel, 22.04, intel

So according to this article : https://www.phoronix.com/review/linux-51535-adl
Intel Alder Lake processors with efficiency cores are fully supported since `5.15.35` , however my kernel version is `5.15.0-46-generic`. Do I have this support? I would like to know before buying new PC. What is the difference between for example `5.15.35` and `5.15.0-35` versions? What does the `0` mean? Are they the same? I want to keep the LTS version with ability to make automatic updates with `sudo apt upgrade` and not thinking about manually installing new versions. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many questions there. A simple answer is that current `5.15` kernels have tat support.

`5.15.35` is a mainline version.

`5.15.0-35` is an Ubuntu version.

The versions are not "same".

The "cpufreq: intel_pstate: ITMT support for overclocked system" has been added to Ubuntu `5.15.0-34` on May 20, 2022.

And the article you are referring to explains all that.

Comment: Thank you. Well, the article explains that they added the support to 5.15.35 but does not explain if it comes in 5.15.0-35 or 34 as you say.

Comment: This is a coincidence that the numbers are close (34 and 35) ;-) Anyway `5.15.0-46` has it.

Comment: To avoid some future questions: Generally, will all the 5.15.x changes in kernel eventually make it into 5.15.0-x Ubuntu versions? Also is it even possible to install 5.15.x kernel running Ubuntu or do I need to wait for the Ubuntu version? I tried to install latest kernel version 5.15.62 using this manual https://linuxhint.com/install-upgrade-latest-kernel-ubuntu-22-04/ but was unsuccessful.

Comment: It depends on kernel maintainers decisions what to backport, but generally these changes are added.I see no reason to install a mainline kernel to Ubuntu unless there is a very good reason.

Comment: Thanks, that was really useful :-)